# Distributed transaction coordinator between SQL Server and Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, msdtc, distributed-transactions

I'm not sure about distributed transaction coordinator so please bare with me on this, I'm probably asking this question wrong. I know distributed transaction coordinator is used in SQL Server and can be used to link 2 SQL Server databases, but I am wondering can distributed transaction coordinator be used to link a SQL Server database and an Oracle database?

Comment: Yes can be done you can manage distributed transaction using linked server. Please read links http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2011/11/28/how-to-configure-msdtc-to-support-oracle-transactions-using-the-oracle-oledb-driver.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa344212(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically it is possible. This [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts001.htm) might help you to setup the distributed transaction processing

Comment: Can you possibly explain how, rather than just link to the documentation?